# Placeholders cutting up on IOS (entry with Custom font)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms.entry

Im using custom fonts on my app. However texts up sides are getting cut on IOS.I fixed it on "Labels" with setting "Line Height" to (1.2).But Placeholders are still cutting.How can i fix it?

[image]

[image: zoom in, look at "S"]
This is my frame box.

```
    <ContentView.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <views:CustomShadowFrame x:Name="FrameBox" Style="{StaticResource CustomizableEntryFrame}" Padding="0">
            <Grid ColumnSpacing="0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ImageColumnWidth,Source={x:Reference View}}"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding ImageSource,Source={x:Reference View}}" Style="{StaticResource CustomizableImageButtonImage}" ></Image>
                <Entry Grid.Column="1" x:Name="EntryValue"  Text="{Binding TextValue,Source={x:Reference View}}"
                       Style="{StaticResource CustomizableEntryEntry}"
                       Placeholder="{Binding PlaceholderText,Source={x:Reference View}}"
                       IsPassword="{Binding IsItPassword,Source={x:Reference View}}"
                       Keyboard="{Binding KeyboardType,Source={x:Reference View}}" >
                </Entry>
            </Grid>
        </views:CustomShadowFrame>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentView.Content>

        <Style x:Key="CustomizableEntryFrame" TargetType="Frame">
            <Setter Property="HasShadow" Value="False" ></Setter>
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="White" ></Setter>
            <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="54" ></Setter>
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="8" ></Setter>
            <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="White" ></Setter>
            <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="CenterAndExpand"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" ></Setter>
        </Style>
            <Style x:Key="CustomizableEntryEntry" TargetType="Entry">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource NormalFont}"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="PlaceholderColor" Value="#5f5d70"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="HeightRequest">
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                    <On Platform="iOS" Value="25"/>
                    <On Platform="Android" Value="35"/>
                </OnPlatform>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Margin">
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                    <On Platform="Android" Value="0,0,15,0"/>
                    <On Platform="iOS" Value="0, 3, 15, -3"/>
                </OnPlatform>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Center"></Setter>
        </Style>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" x:Key="NormalFont">
            <On Platform="Android" Value="CooperHewitt-Medium.otf#Cooper Hewitt Medium" />
            <On Platform="iOS" Value="CooperHewitt-Medium" />
        </OnPlatform>
```

Comment: Can you please add the code about this problem? BTW, I don't see any cutting up in the screenshot.

Comment: Like "E,F,T,G,P etc" letters cutting :( Look closely to E's line.

Comment: Can you give us a sample with simplest code to reproduce this problem? I don't have the custom font on my side and hard to reproduce it.